# How to disable user interaction of a specific CollectionViewCell with condition that update per click

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Each cell is a struct that contains a variable: numberOfRegistration.

If user clicks that cell, numberOfRegistration will +1.

The cell's user interaction will be disable if counter = 5 or more.

I somehow came up with this but it didn't work.

```
struct hourSlot{
    var hoursService:String
    var numberOfRegistration:Int = 0
    var isDisable:Bool = false
    mutating func disable(){
        if numberOfRegistration >= 5{
            isDisable = true
        }
    }
}
```

and in cellForItemAt:

```
var isDisableCell = hoursArray[indexPath.item].isDisable
if isDisableCell{
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Note: hoursArray is an array cointains structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
struct hourSlot{
    var hoursService:String
    var isDisable:Bool = false
    var numberOfRegistration:Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            if numberOfRegistration >= 5 {
                isDisable = true
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

When you change `numberOfRegistration` it'll be reflected to `isDisable` then you can reload that indexpath of the table to refresh

```
var isDisableCell = hoursArray[indexPath.item].isDisable
if isDisableCell{
  cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false   
} 
else {
  cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

Or shortly

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = !(hoursArray[indexPath.item].isDisable)
```

Reload after every change

```
collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item:changedRow, section: 0)])
```

Comment: Wait, do I need to reload anything to apply the change? (Because it's not working)

Comment: It might be a dumb question but what do I need to reload and how to do it?

Comment: check edit if you do it in `didSelectRowAt` then reload there see edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let hourSlot = hoursArray[indexPath.item]
hourSlot.disable()
if hourSlot.isDisable{
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

In order to have isDisable changed you need to call disable() method. And then you can check its variable.

Comment: I guess it is supposed to be `isDisable` instead of `isDisableCell` so I changed it

but it still didn't work